# Jquery ready dom

Tags: jquery, dom, ready

i got a kind of issue of JQuery ( i started few times ago), i have a very BIG html page, and i have a widget at the start of this page, but i did a document.ready so it's waiting that all my page is loaded before to execute which is too long.

So how i can execute jquery just after my widget is loaded ? i tried something like $(myWidget).ready() but it's not working

I hope i'm clear enough

CHeers

Comment: well it's big but can be resume to a very simple version

Comment: <html>DOM<mywidget><myjavascript>DOM<html>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the [documentation of jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) :

```
$(function () {
    // Everything here will be called AFTER the DOM is loaded
    // So it will be called after your widget is loaded
    // but it will wait that your whole page is loaded.
});
```

But now, if you want the Javascript code to be executed just after the widget is ready and not waiting that the *whole page* is loaded, the only (*proper*) way I know is to create the widget via Javascript with some DOM manipulation.
And doing so, you could use the code given by @Robbert.

Then, if you don't mind having a bad code, you can do the javscript **just after** the HTML widget, but this is **awfully wrong** and I don't recommend you to do that.

```
<div class="widget">
    <!-- Your widget html code -->
</div>
<script>
    // your JS code
</script>
```

Based on the three solution given, I would recommend you to generate the Widget directly from javascript. It's better, not intrusive and you don't have to wait that the whole page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You could just add your javascript after that widget and don't have a load event

Comment: What if the widget gets initialized after some kind of event? Wouldn't that screw it up?

Comment: i will try, it's the simplest solution the better most of time ^^

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
widget_function()

$(document).ready(

other JS
)
```

just do the widget outside the document.ready then it wil load before your html